# tornado redirect with parameters

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, tornado

A user logs into my site through oauth via the url

```
http://provemath.org/index?method=google&state=KasQzeMyWQj3YTvF4aZGi9smLUMwXa&code=4/OAeBwzZLSqoHtwBgEHojEQ1_FFO7TK03j5UUyF2Bdng#
```

I don't really like the messiness of the parameters in the URL, and currently it causes an issue when they reload.  So what I'd like to do is redirect them to provemath.org in order to get those parameters out of the URL, but pass those same variables along some *other* way.

Is it possible to do a redirect (something like `self.redirect('http://provemath.org', self.request.uri)`) and pass in some variables *not* through the URL?

It doesn't look like the possibility is built-in:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.redirect

Comment: Is it an option to pass them in an HTTP header? If so, just use `self.set_header("prev-querystring", querystring)` just before the redirect. Another option could be just log them. Also notice that you could be doing this at proxy level (nginx, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a part of the redirect itself, but you can pass this kind of information around with cookies (and this is the usual way of handling an oauth redirect). Typically with oauth you would configure your oauth callback URL to be something like `provemath.org/oauth` (not `provemath.org/index`), and then in your `/oauth` handler you'd process the parameters and set a cookie. If you're using `tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin` this would look like

```
       user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(
            redirect_uri='http://provemath.org/oauth',
            code=self.get_argument('code'))
       self.set_secure_cookie("user", json.dumps(user))
       self.redirect("/")
```

(or save `user` to a database and just put a user id in the cookie)

Comment: So basically as long as the cookie is there, they are 'logged in'.  Even if they logged out of facebook, they would still be logged in at my site.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Logout is always a tricky point with oauth-based login schemes; I think in most cases you have to log out of each site where you used facebook-based authentication separately (or wait for cookies to expire)